# Adding Bootstrap Tabs to a content view

Tags: views, theming, 8, plugins

I've created a custom content type which I want to display in a view using Bootstrap's Tabs component.

I've found [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/theming-views-in-drupal-8-custom-style-plugins/) of sorts, but I'm a bit lost trying to process it all (I'm very new to Drupal).

It looks like it does almost exactly what I need it to. I basically need to display the content I have in that view to be placed inside Bootstrap's Tab markup. I know the theme I'm using already has Bootstrap embedded and available, but I can't seem to figure out to make a "Bootstrap Tabs" option available in the "Style" option of my page view.

Can anyone share some pointers on where to start looking for a solution and on what I need to read up on?

**EDIT:**

I've been following the tutorial and was able to get somewhere with it. Right now, a `Format` option for Bootstrap Tabs shows up when editing the view and, when selected, it is followed by a form questioning which field should be used for navigation - as intended, I recon.

Although right after answering the form question, above the preview area, an error message shows up stating:

> Template "modules/custom/bootstrap3tabs/templates/bootstrap3tabs.html.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "modules/custom/bootstrap3tabs/templates/bootstrap3tabs.html.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.).

Which in turn also shows up in the view after saving.

Can anyone share some pointers on why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

you can also use the https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs for this 
    (The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content, specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding content display instantly, using jQuery. With the 6.x-2.x branch, this can be done in either ajax or non-ajax mode:)
available  for drupal 8

Comment: Thank you for your reply. AFAIK, there is no Drupal 8 port yet, At most, there are dev versions and according to the repository, there hasn't been that much activity since August 2015. But I'll try it out anyway.

Comment: Doesn't work as intended. it borks up when trying to add a new quick tab - goes to a 500 page.